# iphone development: How to open FBWebDialog with pre-defined receivers and no friend list

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send requests to the friends by using FBWebDialog. Is it possible to open FBWebDialog with pre-defined receiver section. I mean, for example I will send request to the friends whose FB ids are 00000 and 11111. is it possible to open FBWebDialog which already has 00000 and 11111 in the receiver section? I also dont want the friend list which comes with the FBWebDialog.

So I just want to have the possibility to send request to the pre-defined receivers.

If there is something which does that other than the FBWebDialog, it is also OK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the standard FBWebDialog class by specifying the 'to' parameter as a comma separated list.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
// 2. Optionally provide a 'to' param to direct the request at
@"000000,111111", @"to",
nil];
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just smashed %d friends! Can you beat it?", nScore]
              title:nil
              parameters:params
              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                  if (error) {
                      // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                      NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                  } else {
                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                          // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                          NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                      } else {
                          NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                  }
}}];
```

Ref: [Facebook iOS SDK Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/)